# Please Identify this adjustable inductor (ferrite-core bobbin)

Tags: rf, transformer, inductor, ferrite

Can anyone identify this component and suggest where to get more of them---or provide a manufacturer/model number? I need more [for an HF radio project](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1683803291860423/) but haven't found them.

These are for hand-winding variable inductors with ~0.1mm wire and then it is tunable by twisting the ferrite-core.  The 2x3 pin arrangement allows for winding your own center-tapped RF transformers:

[image: adjustable bobbin-wound ferrite-core inductor]

Comment: http://www.amidoncorp.com/tunable-inductors/

Comment: They may have been 455kHz intermediate frequency coils made for transistor radios.

Comment: @TimWescott, I think you nailed it.  Any idea if there is an equivalent product sold by Mouser or DigiKey?

Comment: The closest thing I ever saw were pre-made variable inductors by Toko that DigiKey used to sell, but those are long gone.  Variable inductors just aren't current tech, and variable capacitors are getting few and far between -- technology is just marching away from that sort of circuit design.

Comment: I received a few of these in a 50 lb. "Grab box" from Fair Radio Sales in Lima, Ohio almost 50 years ago. Perhaps some could still be found at similar electronics surplus radio equipment suppliers.
In any case, those look more like 10.7 MHz FM BCB IF transformers than 455 kHz AM BCB IF cans.

Comment: @TimWescott Current tech or not, Digi-key still seems to have a [dedicated category](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/adjustable-inductors/72) for variable inductors, though it is one of their smaller categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per @TimWescott in the comments above, [they are (or are similar to) these](http://www.amidoncorp.com/tunable-inductors/).

He also notes that "Variable inductors just aren't current tech, and variable capacitors are getting few and far between -- technology is just marching away from that sort of circuit design."

**Edit, Here they are:**

1. At least for the moment, they are available [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/363215635965) in packs of 20.  I'll post model numbers when the arrive if they are listed on the label so we can know what manufacturer actually provides them.
2. [Plastic Inductor Bobbin](https://onlinetps.com/shop/IFT-Plastic-Bobbin-)
3. [Ferrite Screw for the Bobbin](https://onlinetps.com/shop/Passive-Components/Inductors-Coils-Chokes%20/Ferrite-Screw)
4. #2, #3 do not have shields, but #1 does.

---

Here are a few other resources,  in case someone finds them useful:

- [Material and Winding Reference](https://www.amstzone.org/Amidon-Jan01.pdf)
- [Another (but different) material and winding reference](https://worldradiohistory.com/hd2/IDX-AUSTRALIA/IDX/Amateur-Radio/80s/Amateur-Radio-AU-1988760.pdf)
- ["Secrets of RF Circuit Design: Chapter 4: Winding your own coils"](https://qsl.net/wa3mej/Articles/Transformer%20&%20Baluns/0071455639_ar004.pdf)  references the Amidon model number and gives the number of turns.